# Use $redact to replace sub-documents with "access denied"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've written some `$redact` operation to filter my documents:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { $redact: {
        $cond: {
            if: { "$ifNull" : ["$_acl.READ", false] },
            then: { $cond: {
                if: { $anyElementTrue: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$_acl.READ",
                        as: "myfield",
                        in: { $setIsSubset: [ "$$myfield", ["user1“] ] }
                    }
                }},
                then: "$$DESCEND",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }},
            else: "$$DESCEND",
        }
    }}
])
```

This will remove all (sub)documents, where `_acl.READ` doesn't contain `user1`. But it will keep all (sub)documents where `_acl.READ` is not set.

After the aggregation I can't tell if some information was removed of if it simply wasn't part of the document.

Though I'd like remove sensitive information, but keep some hint which tells that access was denied. I.e.

```
{
    id: ...,
    subDoc1: {
        foo: "bar",
        _acl: {
          READ: [ ["user1"] ]
        }
    },
    subDoc2: {
        _error: "ACCESS DENIED"
    }
}
```

I just can't figure out, how to modify the document while using `$redact`.

Thank you!

Comment: `$redact` does not work like that and only accepts arguments that are either `$$DESCEND`, `$$KEEP` or `$$PRUNE` under the then or else conditions. Unless you use arrays instead it's not really possible to traverse sub-keys of a document and "replace" the content where conditions are not me. With arrays you can do it, but not by using `$redact`.

Comment: Could you give an example using arrays?

Answer (score 4):

The [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline stage is quite unique in the aggregation framework as it is not only capable of recursively descending into the nested structure of a document but also in that it can traverse across all of the keys at any level. It does however still require a concept of "depth" in that a key must either contain a sub-document object or an array which itself is composed of sub-documents.

But what it cannot do is "replace" or "swap-out" content. The only actions allowed here are fairly set, or more specifically [from the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend):

> The argument can be any valid expression as long as it resolves to [$$DESCEND](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#descend), [$$PRUNE](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune), or [$$KEEP](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep) system variables. For more information on expressions, see [Expressions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions).

The possibly misleading statement there is *"The argument can be any valid expression"*, which is in fact true, but it must however return **exactly** the same content as what would be resolved to be present in one of those system variables anyhow.

So in order to give some sort of "Access Denied" response in replacement of the "redacted" content, you would have to process differently. Also you would need to consider the limitations of other operators which could simply not work in a "recursive" or in a manner that requires "traversal" as mentioned earlier.

Keeping with the example from the documentation:

```js
{
   "_id": 1,
   "title": "123 Department Report",
   "tags": [ "G", "STLW" ],
   "year": 2014,
   "subsections": [
       {
           "subtitle": "Section 1: Overview",
           "tags": [ "SI", "G" ],
           "content":  "Section 1: This is the content of section 1."
        },
       {
           "subtitle": "Section 2: Analysis",
           "tags": [ "STLW" ],
           "content": "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
       },
       {
           "subtitle": "Section 3: Budgeting",
           "tags": [ "TK" ],
           "content": {
               "text": "Section 3: This is the content of section3.",
               "tags": [ "HCS" ]
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

If we want to process this to "replace" when matching the "roles tags" of `[ "G", "STLW" ]`, then you would do something like this instead:

```js
var userAccess = [ "STLW", "G" ];
db.sample.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "title": 1,
    "tags": 1,
    "year": 1,
    "subsections": { "$map": {
      "input": "$subsections",
      "as": "el",
      "in": { "$cond": [
        { "$gt": [ 
          { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$$el.tags", userAccess ] }},
          0
        ]},
        "$$el",
        { 
          "subtitle": "$$el.subtitle",
          "label": { "$literal": "Access Denied" }
        }   
      ]}
    }}
  }}
])
```

That's going to produce a result like this:

```js
{
   "_id": 1,
   "title": "123 Department Report",
   "tags": [ "G", "STLW" ],
   "year": 2014,
   "subsections": [
       {
           "subtitle": "Section 1: Overview",
           "tags": [ "SI", "G" ],
           "content":  "Section 1: This is the content of section 1."
        },
       {
           "subtitle": "Section 2: Analysis",
           "tags": [ "STLW" ],
           "content": "Section 2: This is the content of section 2."
       },
       {
           "subtitle" : "Section 3: Budgeting",
           "label" : "Access Denied"
       }
   ]
}
```

Basically, we are rather using the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to process the array of items and pass a condition to each element. In this case the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator first looks at the condition to decide whether the "tags" field here has any [**`$setIntersection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/) result with the `userAccess` variable we defined earlier.

Where that condition was deemed `true` then the element is returned un-altered. Otherwise in the `false` case, rather than remove the element ( not impossible with `$map` but another step), since [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) returns an equal number of elements as it received in "input", you just replace the returned content with something else. In this case and object with a single key and a [**`$literal`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/) value. Being "Access Denied".

So keep in mind what you **cannot** do, being:

- You cannot actually traverse document keys. Any processing needs to be explicit to the keys specifically mentioned.
- The content therefore cannot be in another other form than an array as MongoDB cannot traverse accross keys. You would need to otherwise evaluate conditionally at each key path.
- Filtering the "top-level" document is right out. Unless you really want to add an additional stage at the end that does this:

  ```js
  { "$project": {
    "doc": { "$cond": [
      { "$gt": [ 
        { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$tags", userAccess ] }},
        0
      ]},
      "$ROOT",
      {
        "title": "$title",
        "label": { "$literal": "Access Denied" }
      }
    ]}
  }}
  ```

With all said and done, there really is not a lot of purpose in any of this unless you are indeed intending to actually "aggregate" something at the end of the day. Just making the server do exactly the same filtering of document content that you can do in client code it usually not the best use of expensive CPU cycles.

Even in the basic examples as given, it makes a lot more sense to just do this in client code unless you are really getting a major benefit out of removing entries that do not meet your conditions from being transferred over the network. In your case there is no such benefit, so better to client code instead.